# Power Automate - Extract links in a table

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am wanting to extract link addresses within a table on a web page using Power Automate.

I can extract the link using Get details of an element but this only works for one link in a table.

I can also extract the entire table as text.

I want something that does both and stores the results in a list / table.

Example is as follows. https://www.pdga.com/tour/events
I want the links to all the tournaments in the column 'Name'